# dynamic page nav item alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make a dynamically-loading website that has navigation columns that move around so that the selected/active page is aligned horizontally.

basically, the home page would look something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYFgz.jpg) and then when another nav item is clicked that has others beneath it, another column appears, and all of the selected items align in the center in the yellow bar [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuPLe.jpg)

no idea what to call this, or what to search for in other answers. what's the best way to make this happen?

thanks!

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a code example in your question.

Comment: i have no code, just wireframes. i'm trying to see if what i want to do is possible before i begin coding

Comment: In that case your question will likely be closed as off-topic because it is too broad and you haven't shown any effort in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As user [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323558/dynamic-page-nav-item-alignment#comment54444986_33323558) said your question is too vague without you putting forth any effort.

However the idea you want to achieve is possible and could *probably* be done by stacking [Scotch Panels](https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-panels) on each other with the final one loading the content.

I will state that this is not a common use cause and will probably create a frustrating UI as you are introducing more complicated filtering of content than normal navigation mechanism. More power to you to figure it out but always think of the user experience.